# Can't reach High Hrothgar because a sabercat is in my way. How can I evade or handle that?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On my way to High Hrothgar (I'm a level 11 thief mostly aimed at sneaking and archery) I meet a sabertooth cat on the 7000 steps. There is no way to go around it and it kills me in 2 blows.

I tried doing large damage to it with shouts, magic and everything else, but I can't kill him. I even lost my housecarl, it can't fight it.

I was wondering if I could find a potion of invisibility somewhere. Else I'll have to wait for the Ethereal shout and run like hell in hope he'll let me pass.

How would you bypass this "problem"?

Comment: Note, i decided to just do some other quests meanwhile. I went to riften to start thief related quests, but obviously i'd like to meet the graybeards before i reach level 30 :)

Comment: I didn't meet the GreyBeards until level 40+.  Saving the world is easy to forget about when there's looting to do! No polluting though...

Comment: I used to meet the GreyBeards before level 15... Then I took an arrow to the knee.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot and you can still kill dragons if i'm right, i've yet to meet another one but i think you can meet some without meeting up with delphine...

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin - Yes, I was fighting dragons long before I met the Greybeards OR Delphine

Comment: If the cat needs 2 blows to kill you, why not spam potions on yourself between the hits?

Comment: Around that level I was smithing dragon armor so I had no problem with the silly cats

Comment: Do you have any shouts yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would buy a horse and run past it.  They only cost 1000 gold which shouldn't take too long to build up as you work on other quests.

Alternatively you could try to find a rock or some object along the path that you can jump onto where the sabrecat can't reach you and try to shoot it with arrows from there.

Comment: Interresting, i'll try that out and flag if it works, please do provide other methods just in case :)

Comment: Better yet, steal a horse at a stable anywhere and when you come back, just pay the bounty if they're still looking for you. Much cheaper.

Answer (score 5):

You can Shout him off the cliff with your "Unrelenting Voice" shout.
"Become Ethereal" wont work,since you can only stay untouched for a while.

If you are a wood elf,you can use your racial to charm him so you dont have to fight him.

Invisibility potions can also help.
You can force him to fight other near mobs, just by running near them with the cat pursuiting you.

Or, you can go to Whiterun, enter the "Drunk Huntsman" and pay 500 Gold for an Archer Household, let her tanking the cat while you shoot decent arrows (like steel, or dwarven since you are level 11) with a poisoned / enchanted bow (any fire enchant will do)

Comment: #1 wont work as you need to go to high hrothgar to learn the last words of the shout, otherwise it is very weak.

Comment: @JoethePerson True. My bad Fus isn't enought

Answer (score 3):

[Kyne's Peace](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kyne%27s_Peace) can be obtained literally 30 feet from Ivarstead. It's like they're saying "here there be monsters" and giving you a monster pacifier. But then there's the troll...

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same problem, my solution was to hire a mercenary. She was able to keep aggro long enough for me to do my dirty work, also shouting the cat off of the cliff worked well.

Comment: The first level shout doesn't push far enough i tried that option even tried to trick the cat to be right beside the ledge. If i had talked to the greybeards, then it wouldnt be a problem...

Comment: I found shouting near the edge can give you some good dps time on the cat while it struggles to get back in range to fight you.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other suggestions work, try a Calm/Fear spell. You might not be able to cast a strong enough version, so look into finding a scroll. The court wizard in Dragonsreach tends to have a few for sale.

Answer (score 0):

Use Kyne's Peace; it soothes any animal, but not people or dragons.

Answer (score -2):

get to level 25 with a archery skill of 100 then blow it away with one shot sending it flying 50 yards.